# Installing Ruby via RVM fails to configure

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby via RVM by running `rvm install 1.9.3` but am getting a bunch of errors:

> Error running `env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --prefix=/Users/kuzjaved/.rvm/usr`, please read `/Users/kuzjaved/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/yaml/configure.log`
>
> Error running `make`, please read `/Users/kuzjaved/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/yaml/make.log`
>
> Error running `env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/kuzjaved/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327 --with-opt-dir=/Users/kuzjaved/.rvm/usr`, please read `/Users/kuzjaved/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/configure.log`
>
> There has been an error while running `configure`. Halting the installation.

I'v then tried:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Same errors here too! What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you read the logs that are mentioned? Perhaps these contain something usefull.

Comment: ruby is installed by Apple on OSX albeit not the latest version

Comment: Yes i want to install latest version

Comment: In my experience, most of the times this is caused because you have to enable the command-line tools in xcode, and sometimes this has to be repeated after updating xcode as well. Now if that is the case, this would be very clear from the logs as well. Good luck.

Comment: thanks. now i cannot seem to find any erb files.....

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make the whole process simpler, download **RailsInstaller** for OSX from http://railsinstaller.org/

It is bundled with all the common packages needed for a full Rails stack; All dependencies are covered for a generic rails installation.

Answer (score 2):

Get [home-brew](https://brew.sh/).Then

```
brew install ruby
```

Make sure Xcode is installed, and all the command line plugins too.

Comment: It says error when I install homebrew. I have installed xcode and changed in preferences.....

Comment: it does not let me type password....

Comment: ok homebrew is installed.....

Comment: here are the errors:     Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config

Comment: Not sure that's an error. That's just home-brew warning you of potential conflicts later on. What's the actual error?

Comment: @nes1983 FYI the OP opened a [new question with his Homebrew problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022392/homebrew-errors-on-osx-lion).

Answer (score 2):

RVM isn't the only Ruby version manager. There's plenty of others, see [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/ruby_version_management). There's also [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby), which isn't on that list.

To uninstall RVM, run `rvm implode` and restart the Terminal.

Comment: there is a lot more complete list here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/help/alt.md

Answer (score 2):

RVM comes with a command that describes what you need for ruby:

```
rvm requirements
```

It should be displayed to you on first ruby installation, but if you missed it you can always read it again.

Also the output you posted includes paths to additional log files, you did not show them - I guess there are some clues that would show what is wrong.

Finally I do online support for RVM users here: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm

Answer (score 1):

```
$ rvm requirement
Unrecognized command line argument: 'requirement' ( see: 'rvm usage' )
```

My edit to replace `rvm requirement` by `rvm requirements` in mpapis answer has been quickly rejected.
I am sorry to have to insist. I'm using a recent version `rvm 1.16.6`.

Comment: I have to be tired while writing that response, of course it is `requirements` not `requirement`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with `rbenv` (before you should get rid off rvm, launching command `rvm implode` and removing rvm settings from ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc:

Get [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and launch the following commands:

```
brew install rbenv 
brew install ruby-build
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Exit from Terminal and reopen it. Then you can install a ruby with

```
rbenv install 1.9.3-p327
```

or your preferred ruby, finding it from `rbenv install --list`